# Japanese SRT files garbled, can't determine encoding to fix with iconv

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, iconv, mojibake, srt

I have an srt file, excerpt:

```
2
00:00:36,208 --> 00:00:39,667
Èá óå óêïôþóù, ÃïõÜéíôæåëóôéí!

3
00:00:57,917 --> 00:01:00,917
Ãéáôß ôñÝ÷åéò, ÃïõÜéíôæåëóôéí;
Óïõ ðÞñá äþñï ãåíåèëßùí.

4
00:01:00,958 --> 00:01:03,208
Äåí ðåéñÜæåé, äåí ÷ñåéáæüôáí
íá ìïõ ðÜñåéò êÜôé.

5
00:01:03,250 --> 00:01:06,375
Óïõ ðÞñá ëßãï êïñìü äÝíôñïõ.
Êáé èá ôï öáò.

6
00:01:06,417 --> 00:01:08,875
Ùñáßá. ¸ôóé êé áëëéþò
èá Ýôñùãá êïñìü.

7
00:01:08,917 --> 00:01:10,208
Äåí èá Ýôñùãåò.

8
00:01:10,208 --> 00:01:11,000
Íáé. ÂëÝðåéò...

9
00:01:11,000 --> 00:01:12,417
...üëá ôá ðñÜãìáôá ðïõ Þèåëåò
íá ìïõ êÜíåéò...

10
00:01:12,417 --> 00:01:13,958
...ó÷åäßáæá íá ôá êÜíù ìüíïò ìïõ.
```

Supposedly these are japanese subtitles, but obviously it is garbled from encoding issue.  I am trying to figure out how to correct it and convert to UTF-8 ultimately.  Anyone have any ideas?

File output: UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text, with CRLF line terminators

File can be obtained here for testing:
http://www.opensubtitles.org/en/subtitles/5040215/the-incredible-burt-wonderstone-ja

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have is a document that has been transcoded from the [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) character set to the [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoding scheme, but the document source was coded in the [ISO-8859-7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-7) character set. After the transcoding to UTF-8, a U+FEFF byte order mark ([BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)) has been added and a few quotation marks (U+201C, U+201D).

The language is Greek and 2nd subtitle sequence when corrected is:

```
2
00:00:36,208 --> 00:00:39,667
Θα σε σκοτώσω, Γουάιντζελστιν!
```

The English translation is "[I'll kill you, Gouaintzelstin!](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/%CE%98%CE%B1%20%CF%83%CE%B5%20%CF%83%CE%BA%CE%BF%CF%84%CF%8E%CF%83%CF%89%2C%20%CE%93%CE%BF%CF%85%CE%AC%CE%B9%CE%BD%CF%84%CE%B6%CE%B5%CE%BB%CF%83%CF%84%CE%B9%CE%BD!)".

To reverse/correct it:

1. Decode the document from the UTF-8 encoding scheme
2. Remove all code-points greater than U+00FF
3. Encode the document using the ISO-8859-1 encoding
4. Transcode the document using the ISO-8859-7 encoding to the UTF-8 encoding scheme.

An implementation of the above in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Encode qw[];

(@ARGV == 1 && -f $ARGV[0])
  or die qq[Usage: $0 <file>];

my $file = shift @ARGV;

my ($octets, $string);

# Read all the octets from the file
$octets = do {
    open my $fh, '<:raw', $file
      or die qq[Could not open '$file' for reading: '$!'];
    local $/; <$fh>
};

# Decode the octets using the UTF-8 encoding scheme
$string = Encode::decode('UTF-8', $octets, Encode::FB_CROAK);

# Remove all code points greater than U+00FF
$string =~ s/[^\x00-\xFF]//g; 

# Encode the string using the ISO-8859-1 encoding
$octets = Encode::encode('ISO-8859-1', $string);

# Decode the octets using the ISO-8859-7 encoding
$string = Encode::decode('ISO-8859-7', $octets);

# Encode the string using the UTF-8 encoding
$octets = Encode::encode('UTF-8', $string);

# Output the octets on standard output
print $octets;
```

Comment: Very good sleuthing on that chansen!  Too bad the file wasn't Japanese as it was marked, but that has nothing to do with this really.  I did try the script and end up with a perfectly encoded greek srt file.